# Turning a blog(with comments) into a beautiful texbook

Tags: book-design

I have a blog that I'd like to turn into a printed book. The blog isn't particularly mathematical, but does have some photos, and lots of text.

This question:  [Typesetting non-scientific material for the first time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/typesetting-non-scientific-material-for-the-first-time?rq=1) provides a nice start for presenting things in a book style, and from my early experiments with the Memoir class, this seems to be a nice start.

However, blog's have comments, and thus present a slightly different challenge.

**What packages or commands would tastefully present comments under a blog post?**

Comment: Here http://www.amazon.com/TeXbook-Donald-Knuth/dp/0201134489 is a beautiful TeXbook. ;-)

Comment: Yes, like the rest of the users on this site, I am familiar with the TeXbook.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Good one, but now I can't edit the title to correct the typo `:)`

Comment: What is your question exactly? Is it about design/format? Is it about automating/streamlining the transfer of contents from your blog into your LaTeX document? Be more specific.

Comment: Design and format mostly. I don't mind copy/pasting the text, and formatting the pictures. Thanks for the clarifying question.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke How dare you use the indefinite article?!

Comment: This seems to be off topic for several reasons: it is too vague (we know almost nothing about the content, for example, which will surely affect the choice of formatting); it is primarily opinion-based (there are rules of typography but they leave much room for variation and, anyway, this is not a site about typography); and it has only the most passing connection with TeX and friends. If it was a question about how to implement a desired design, it would at least be on-topic. But it is hard to see how anybody could answer this here, let alone give a uniquely correct solution.

Comment: Oh stackexchange, you never fail to produce a swath of unhelpful commenters. This is why we can't have nice things. Although, here is a perfectly useful and civil discussion of a similar topic: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/typesetting-non-scientific-material-for-the-first-time?rq=1 but less centralized to a blog output. The main differences between my question and that? I want to include photos and the main subject matter is a blog, with comments and such. So @cfr, feel free to comment on that one too. ^_^

Comment: @BBischof I'm sorry, but I have to agree with cfr on this one. Perhaps your question is well suited to other fora, but  I think that it doesn't, in its current from, have its place here. However, all is not lost: it's never too late to improve your question and, perhaps, get valuable answers.

Comment: Instead of railing at @cfr that we don't have an instant answer for a somewhat vague question, help us to help you. For instance, add a screenshot to your question, or tell us how you plan to capture the content, and in what format. Or tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have edited the question to improve it, and narrow the focus in accordance with @Jubobs and Brent.Longborough's suggestions.

Comment: @BBischof Much better. Voting to reopen.

Comment: If you want each comment to be visually offset from the others, my suggestion would be to use [tcolorbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).  Not the most lightweight solution, but you could nest related comments in a series of overlapping boxes, and there is the possibility to break boxes across pages.  If you can scrape your comments, etc., into a `.csv`, then the package [datatool](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) is useful for iterating over the `.csv`.  Memoir, as you mentioned, is a useful class for doing fancy books in general.